# WMS GetCapabilities is returning bad request error

Tags: wms

We are trying to use the DGCA APIs for getting the capabilities of the vector layers. However we are getting the below error.

[image]

Using: https://digitalsky.dgca.gov.in/wms/getZones?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/413276/edit) and add the URL as text.

Comment: Have you tried with &version=1.3.0?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 3):

The service is working, as the below WMS 1.1.1 GetMap request shows, but does not respond to a GetCapabilities request (with or without version number).  It is highly likely that the service is not intended to be used by external clients and that the GetCapabilities response is disabled (it's not a request error).  You won't be able to use software clients like QGIS to access the service because they require a working GetCapabilities response.

[image: GetMap request]

You mention `vector layers` in your question, you should note that the WMS service provides images, not vector data.